# Vertx HTTPS Server, key password different from key store key passord

Tags: java, https, keystore, jks, jsse

I'm using vertx 3.5.3.
I'm trying to enable HTTPS for a simple vertx HTTP server. I have a key store, let's say `keystore.jks`protected with a password `keystore_password`. This key store contains a key that is protected with a password `key_password` that is different from `keystore_passord`.

I'm configuring my HTTP server this way :

```
    JksOptions keystoreOptions = new JksOptions()
        .setPath(get("http.server.keystore"))
        .setPassword(get("http.server.keystore.password"));

    HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions()
            .setSsl(true)
            .setKeyStoreOptions(keystoreOptions);

   vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions)
    .requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("Hello World!"))
    .listen(8080, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            startFuture.complete();
        } else {
            startFuture.fail(res.cause());
            System.out.println(res.cause());
        }
    });
```

My server doesn't start and I get this following exception `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`. I can see from vertx code that my key store is loaded with the password from the `keystoreOptions` :

```
  return new KeyStoreHelper(loadJKSOrPKCS12("JKS", jks.getPassword(), value), jks.getPassword());
```

Class `KeyStoreHelper.java`, method `public static KeyStoreHelper create(VertxInternal vertx, KeyCertOptions options)`.

Once the keys store loaded, I can also see that my key is loaded with the same password in class `KeyStoreHelper.java` :

```
KeyManagerFactory fact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
fact.init(store, password != null ? password.toCharArray(): null);
```

Am I using the right way to configure HTTPS? Is there a way to specify different passwords for my key store and key? Or do I have to set the same password for both?

Comment: Java JSSE doesn't cope by default with this situation. Do you really need it?

Comment: yes, for security reasons, passwords are like underwears, it don't share ;-)